# Why did my auth.log file get cleared?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have an Ubuntu SSH server that is connected to an open port. I use an 18 character alphanumerical password and also google two factor authentication for security purposes but i forgot to close my port over night. This meant that when i later checked on my auth.log file it showed authentication attempts which often happen. The strange part is that before Dec 29 00:17 all the information is cleared. This has happened before but because I'm having authentication problems myself, it's frightening.

Is it normal that my file was cleared? And if so, what could have caused it?

P.S. I'm pretty new to servers :)

Comment: Logs are rotated regularly (cf. `/etc/logrotate.d`). It means the old `auth.log` became `auth.log.1`, `auth.log.1` became `auth.log.2` (maybe gzipped), etc.